# Breaking up a with statement

Tags: python

Originally, I have been opening and simultaneously reading through two files with something like this:

```
with open(file1, 'r') as R1:
    with open(file2, 'r') as R2:
        ### my code
```

But now the input file names may sometimes be gzipped. So, I thought to split up the `with` statement and use an `if` statement to handle the two scenarios with something like this:

```
if zipped:
    R1 = gzip.open(file1, 'r')
    R2 = gzip.open(file2, 'r')
else:
    R1 = open(file1, 'r')
    R2 = open(file2, 'r')

with R1:
    with R2:
        ### my code
```

Does the second code function like the first? Or is there even a better way to do this?

Comment: You could wrap the `zipped` predicate in a function that wraps `gzip.open` or `open` invoked on the function's file name argument.

Comment: @dfri: thus making the file type transparent to the `open` (well, at least if the data, zipped or not, is exactly the same). I'd sure like to see that as a full how-to answer!

Comment: Where does `zipped` come from? If it's dependent on the filename of `file1`, or the magic header, or something like that, then you probably do want a wrapper function that transparently figures it out—but, given that `zipped` seems to be always either true for both `file1` and `file2`, or for neither, I'm not sure that makes sense here.

Comment: @usr2564301 abarnerts solution of using the predicate to store a callable and invoke as part of the `with` expression is better.

Comment: @dfri I think the major difference between using a wrapper or just store the function in a variable is whether the `zipped` flag is some external information (which we'd have to pass into the wrapper function, making it more verbose without being any more readable) or something we can figure out from `file1` and `file2` (and know they'll always be consistent) (in which case the wrapper could be transparent, which I think is nicer).

Comment: @abarnert good point; if the logic of the predicate is e.g. simply checking the extensions of the file names, this would be neater to put in a wrapper rather than into e.g. a local `zipped` variable at the call site.

Comment: @dfri Yeah, that's a better way to put what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing *mostly* makes sense, but it has one problem.

---

File objects are context managers that `close` themselves on `__exit__`. As the [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) docs make clear, that includes the `GzipFile` objects returned by `gzip.open`:

> `GzipFile` supports the [`io.BufferedIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) interface, including iteration and the `with` statement.

So, if you write `with f:` on an opened regular file or `GzipFile`, that guarantees that `close` will be called after the `with` statement.

In Python 2.7, the details are slightly different, but it works the same way. In Python 2.6, a `GzipFile` was *not* a context manager. But there's a very easy solution (that's worth knowing about for other types, even if you don't care about Python 2.6): you can wrap anything with a `close` method in [`closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) to get a context manager that calls that `close` on `__exit__`. So, you could write:

```
with contextlib.closing(R1):
```

… and it would work on `R1` whether it's a file object, or some other kind of thing (like a 2.6 `GzipFile`) that doesn't know how to be a context manager.

---

However, what happens if `R1` opens successfully, but `R2` fails? Then you haven't even gotten into the `with R1:` when the exception is raised, so you never close `R1`.

You could fix this by doing the `with R1` before opening `R2`:

```
if zipped:
    R1 = gzip.open(file1, 'r')
else:
    R1 = open(file1, 'r')
with R1:
    if zipped:
        R2 = gzip.open(file2, 'r')
    else:
        R2 = open(file2, 'r')
    with R2:
```

Or you could use an [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack).

But there's a much simpler solution here: Both `gzip.open` and `open` are callable objects, so you can store them in a variable, and call it later. Since they have the same signature, and you want to call them with the exact same arguments, using that variable is trivial:

```
if zipped:
    zopen = gzip.open
else:
    zopen = open
with zopen(file1, 'r') as R1:
    with zopen(file2, 'r') as R2:
```

And notice that you can make this a lot more concise without making it any less readable:

```
zopen = gzip.open if zipped else open
with zopen(file1, 'r') as R1, zopen(file2, 'r') as R2:
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it your original way by creating a function that checks what kind of file it is.

```
def open_or_gzip_open(file_name, permissions='r'):
    if file_name.endswith('gz'):
        R1 = gzip.open(file_name, 'r')
    else:
        R1 = open(file_name, 'r')
    return R1
```

You can open both files on one line:

```
with open_or_gzip_open('text.txt') as p1, open_or_gzip_open('text2.txt') as p2:
    print(p1, p2)
```

~

Answer (score 2):

The second code does work like the first, as long as `zipped` is `False`.

One important thing to note, though, is that you don't have to nest your with statements. Instead you can do something like:

```
with open(file1) as R1, open(file2) as R2:
    ###code
```

(Also, the function `open` has the `'r'` parameter by default, so you don't have to include it.)